# can't open jpg with weird file name

Tags: html, jpeg, encode

I have a CMS that shows JPG's that people have uploaded.
It gives a list of files and the user clicks on it to display it.
Some with long/complex file names won't open.
For instance:

```
s54674_MACLEOD_COZY ANGEL 19-3875 191209-115334 T# NO 4 X (4)
```

which is encoded as

```
s54674_MACLEOD_COZY%20ANGEL%2019-3875%20191209-115334%20T#%20NO%204%20X%20(4).jpg
```

will not open in the browser.
I get a 404 error.

These are valid JPG's. I'd rather not rename them.
Is there some way to make it open in the browser?

Comment: decodeURI("s54674_MACLEOD_COZY%20ANGEL%2019-3875%20191209-115334%20T#%20NO%204%20X%20(4).jpg")

Comment: I was under the impression that the browser did that automatically. Simple. thanks

Comment: This might be because of the #. Everything after the # is not part of the file name. The # needs to be encoded - why isn't it encoded?